# How do I customize the VariablesView in plug-in?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, customization

I want to customize the VariablesView. Do I have to extend VariablesView? How do I do that? What changes do I have to make in plugin.xml to make it work?

Comment: You can't. All you can do is use the various extension points that the debug plugins provide and the various event listeners.

Comment: Also see [Eclipse API Rules of Engagement](https://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-API-Use/index.html) which tells you what you can and can't do.